# Excel Autofill nth cell value in left direction

Tags: excel, autofill

These are the cells I have

| T | 1 | 2 | 3 | H | 1 | 2 | 3 | A | 1 | 2 | 3 | N | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I am trying to use autofill to fill in left direction order

| N | A | H | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

When I get K,1,2,3 in the first table,
I just want to insert a cell in the very left side of the second table, drag, and automatically fill in the cell with K, and so on.

Any idea for nth cell autofill data in left direction order in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My results are here..

[image: Result]

=LET(a,B1:Q1,b,TEXTJOIN(,,IF(ISTEXT(a),a,"")),MID(b,SEQUENCE(,LEN(b),LEN(b),-1),1))

=MID(TEXTJOIN(,,IF(ISTEXT(B1:Q1),B1:Q1,"")),SEQUENCE(,SUMPRODUCT(--ISTEXT(B1:Q1)),SUMPRODUCT(--ISTEXT(B1:Q1)),-1),1)

Comment: Good idea to use `ISTEXT` function.

Comment: Thank you @DavidLeal sir, things are learning from like you people.

Comment: Thank you reminded me the `ISTEXT` function exist. I updated my answer to include a solution using this function.

Answer (score 2):

Using the character identification number, you can add or subtract like classic numbers and display a sequence of orthographic characters.

From your first cell, example "A" in A1

Write instead of your second cell example "B" in E1, replace "B" with: `=CHAR(CODE(A1) + 1)`

Then take your 3 cells : B | 1 | 2 | 3 and stretch your selection, if you don't want to increment the numbers, select "copy cells" and your letter sequence will be done automatically.

Finally it's look like that :

[image]

If you need a character break such as A | D | G you can do + 3 instead of + 1

***Ps :** CHAR is for CHARACTER in English, if your Excel is in another language, this formula can change for example CAR for French version.

Have a good cells !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking only for capital letters as per your sample data. You can try the following in cell `R1`:

```
=INDEX(A1:P1,SORT(TOROW(XMATCH(CHAR(ROW(65:90)), A1:P1),2),,-1,1))
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition:

```
=LET(r, A1:P1, INDEX(r,SORT(TOROW(XMATCH(CHAR(ROW(65:90)), r),2),,-1,1)))
```

**UPDATE**: Taking the idea suggested by @Manoj's answer of using `ISTEXT` function, then it can be solved as follows:

```
=LET(r, A1:P1, f, FILTER(r, ISTEXT(r)), SORTBY(f,
 SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(f),COLUMNS(f),-1)))
```

It is more generic since it discriminates between numbers and letters.

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]